# Duas action para uma mesma View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc

Tenho estas duas action:

```
public ActionResult Lista(int PessoaId, string Nome, string Twitter) 
{
    Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
    p.PessoaId = PessoaId;
    p.Nome = Nome;
    p.Twitter = Twitter;

    return View(p);

}

public ActionResult Lista2(FormCollection form)
{
    Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
    p.PessoaId = Convert.ToInt32(form["PessoaId"]);
    p.Nome = form["Nome"]; ;
    p.Twitter = form["Twitter"]; ;

    return View(p);

}
```

Tenho esta View:

```
@model Hello.Models.Pessoa
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Lista";
}

<h2>Lista</h2>

<div>
    <b>PessoaId</b>
</div>
<div>
    @Model.PessoaId
</div>

<div>
    <b>Nome</b>
</div>
<div>
    @Model.Nome
</div>

<div>
    <b>Twitter</b>
</div>
<div>
    @Model.Twitter
</div>
```

Eu não posso adicionar duas action para uma mesma View? Tentei adicionar a mesma View que adicionei na primeira action na segunda action, mas não foi permitido.

Comment: é ASPNET .....?

Comment: Sim, é ASPNET!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Eu não posso adicionar duas action para uma mesma View?

Sim **PODE**, é só especificar o nome da sua `View` nas duas `Action`, ***exemplo***:

```cs
public ActionResult Lista(int PessoaId, string Nome, string Twitter) 
{
    Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
    p.PessoaId = PessoaId;
    p.Nome = Nome;
    p.Twitter = Twitter;

    return View("NomeDaView", p); 

}

public ActionResult Lista2(FormCollection form)
{
    Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
    p.PessoaId = Convert.ToInt32(form["PessoaId"]);
    p.Nome = form["Nome"]; ;
    p.Twitter = form["Twitter"]; ;

    return View("NomeDaView", p);

}
```

Onde está ***NomeDaView*** coloque o nome do arquivo `.cshtml`, exemplo `Lista.cshtml`, então, `return View("Lista", p);`.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Controller.View Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [ViewResult Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.118).aspx)